# Convert PNG file to bitmap without a header

Tags: javascript, node.js, arduino

I need to prepare a bitmap source stream for the Arduino device (with e-ink display). The data comes from a PNG file. I need a "raw" image data without a header. Just 1 and 0 of each pixel of the image (black or white pixel on the screen). Unfortunately, I don't know how to remove a header and convert a PNG file to a bitmap. This is the code (NodeJS) I use for now:

```js
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

const server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  res.setHeader('content-type', 'application/octet-stream');

  fs.readFile('sample.png', function(err, data) {
    res.end(data);
  });
});

server.listen(3000);
```

When I use a BMP file as a source it works almost well, but I need do it with a PNG file.

This is the way I read stream on my Arduino:

```cpp
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFiMulti.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
ESP8266WiFiMulti WiFiMulti;

#include <GxEPD.h>
#define ROTATION 1
#include <GxGDEW0583T7/GxGDEW0583T7.cpp>
#include <GxIO/GxIO_SPI/GxIO_SPI.cpp>
#include <GxIO/GxIO.cpp>

GxIO_Class io(SPI, 5, 0, 2);
GxEPD_Class display(io, 2, 12);

#define X_RES 448
#define Y_RES 600

void displayImage() {
      uint32_t cursor = 0;
      uint8_t eightPixels;
      boolean initialized = false;
      int len = http.getSize();
      uint8_t buff[256] = { 0 };

      WiFiClient * stream = http.getStreamPtr();

      while(http.connected() && (len > 0 || len == -1)) {
        size_t size = stream->available();

        if(size) {
          int c = stream->readBytes(buff, ((size > sizeof(buff)) ? sizeof(buff) : size));

          for (int offset = 0; offset < c; offset++) {
            if (!initialized) {
              initialized = true;
              display.init();
              display.setRotation(1);
            }

            eightPixels = buff[offset];

            if (cursor < X_RES*Y_RES) {
              for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                if ((eightPixels >> (7-i)) & 0x01){
                  display.drawPixel((cursor+i)%X_RES, (cursor+i)/X_RES, GxEPD_BLACK);
                }
              }
              cursor+=8;
            }
          }

          if(len > 0) {
            len -= c;
          }
        }
        delay(1);
      }
      display.update();
    }
}
```

If you can help me somehow I'd be very grateful.

Comment: The least effort is probably to install `node-canvas`, draw your image on a 2d context, and then directly work with the context's `imageData`. As long as it doesn't have to run on the Arduino itself, the fact that it's not super fast (although it's certainly fast enough) and needs some 80MB for node-canvas to work (it's a Pango-based canvas API emulator) is basically irrelevant.

Comment: @Laudinio Maybe some of different PNG-to-bytearray can help? For example: https://github.com/arian/pngjs

Comment: Use an image processing library.